# select(vore) sometimes calls 'vore' column but sometimes also 'vore_imp' column

Tags: r, select, dplyr

While using R, I figured that I can call multiple columns using the common word in column names. However, I am confused that sometimes only the column with exactly identical column name is called and sometimes multiple columns which contain that column name in their column names are also called. And I don't see any difference between the codes:

.

**Exhibit A**

`msleep %>% select(genus, vore, conservation) %>% na.omit`

This code gives me three columns: 'genus', 'vore', 'conservation'

**Exhibit B**

`library(VIM)`
`msleep %>% select(genus, vore, conservation) %>% na.omit %>% kNN(k=5)`

This code, however, gives me 6 columns: 'genus', 'vore', conservation' and 'genus_imp', 'vore_imp', 'conservation_imp'

.

I don't quite see the notable difference between these two lines of codes, so I am confused. How can I tell whether the dplyr::select() function will give me columns with exactly identical column names or not?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `select` function does not change in both the code. `select` function returns the columns with exactly identical column names but because you are applying `kNN` function in the second case which returns an imputed dataset with additional columns you get `genus_imp`,  `vore_imp` and  `conservation_imp` columns.

```
library(VIM)

step1 <- msleep %>% 
  select(genus, vore, conservation) %>% 
  na.omit 
step1

# A tibble: 52 x 3
#   genus         vore  conservation
#   <chr>         <chr> <chr>       
# 1 Acinonyx      carni lc          
# 2 Aplodontia    herbi nt          
# 3 Blarina       omni  lc          
# 4 Bos           herbi domesticated
# 5 Callorhinus   carni vu          
# 6 Canis         carni domesticated
# 7 Capreolus     herbi lc          
# 8 Capri         herbi lc          
# 9 Cavis         herbi domesticated
#10 Cercopithecus omni  lc          
# … with 42 more rows
```

This first step return the exact same 3 columns but after adding `kNN` function you get more columns.

```
step1 %>% kNN(k=5)

#           genus    vore conservation genus_imp vore_imp conservation_imp
#1       Acinonyx   carni           lc     FALSE    FALSE            FALSE
#2     Aplodontia   herbi           nt     FALSE    FALSE            FALSE
#3        Blarina    omni           lc     FALSE    FALSE            FALSE
#4            Bos   herbi domesticated     FALSE    FALSE            FALSE
#5    Callorhinus   carni           vu     FALSE    FALSE            FALSE
#....
#....
```

If needed you can again add `select` `step1 %>% kNN(k=5) %>%  select(genus, vore, conservation)` to select those 3 columns.